# Android google map inside fragment not showing map

Tags: android, google-maps

Have a map inside a fragment, just trying to do the basic thing of showing Sydney. Has the watermark, but its just blank.

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        map_view.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        map_view.onResume()
        MapsInitializer.initialize(context)
        map_view.getMapAsync(this)
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"))
        val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12f).build()
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
private Marker sydney;
private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
private GoogleMap mMap;


override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

       sydney =  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(SYDNEY).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"))
        val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder().target(SYDNEY).zoom(12f).build()
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
    }
```

You can refer this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker) for more examples.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

are u implements OnMapReadyCallback on your class fragment? like:

```
class MylocationMap : Fragment() ,OnMapReadyCallback{}
```